# union() function does not work properly when taking union of vector with other data type

Tags: r

I have variable which is vector and contain the row names. I want to take the unnion of this vector with the row name of other matrix, but when I do this, it does not work properly. basically it put all things together and does not care about the duplicates,....

Here is my effort:

```
step 1: put the names in vector, which I read it from list of matrix :

name<-c()
name<-lapply(ismr0, function(x){

name<-union(name, rownames(x))
return(name)

})

> length(name)
[1] 733
>
```

Second step which does not work properly;

```
     rn <- union(rownames(ismr0[[1]]), name)
> length(rn)
[1] 1180
> 

> ismr0[[1]][1:4,]
             mature        RPM
MIMAT0000062 mature 49791.5560
MIMAT0000063 mature 92858.1285
MIMAT0000064 mature 10418.8532
MIMAT0000065 mature   404.7618
>
```

But I would expected to have length 733, because row names of ismr0[[1]] is subset of the names in name variable .

Would someone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you show what is in `ismr0` variable?

Comment: Are you trying to go through `ismr0` list and collect all `MIMATXXX` ids?

Comment: I did it in first step and now are stored in vector called name,  now I wnat to compute the union of  name and row names of ismr0[[1]], which comes out to wrong answer. I think becase the name is vector and rownames(ismr0[[1]]) is not, .....but I don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed in comments, you are using union on character vector and list. If we need to get all unique rownames from list then try this example:

```
#dummy data
a<-matrix(1:4,ncol=1)
b<-matrix(1:4,ncol=1)
c<-matrix(1:4,ncol=1)
rownames(a) <- letters[c(2,3,5,7)]
rownames(b) <- letters[c(2,4,5,7)]
rownames(c) <- letters[c(2,3,6,7)]
ismr0 <-list(a,b,c)

#get unique names
name <- unique(unlist(lapply(ismr0,rownames)))

#check with union
rn <- union(rownames(ismr0[[1]]), name)
length(name)==length(rn)
```

Comment: Strange enough, when I run my your code : name <- unique(unlist(lapply(ismr0,rownames))) , I get length of name 833, but when I run my code(step 1 in original post), I get length of name 733. what could be the bug and which one is correct ?

Comment: I guess `ismr0` contains 733 data.frames, which present together 833 different lines.

Comment: Greate solution zx8754

Answer (score 1):

You don't get what you expect because `lapply` returns a list. I ran an example of a list with 3 data.frames and it gave me :

```
[[1]]
[1] "l1" "l2" "l3" "l4" "l5"    # first df rownames

[[2]]
[1] "l6"  "l7"  "l8"  "l9"  "l10"    # second df rownames

[[3]]
[1] "l11" "l12" "l13" "l14" "l15"    # third df rownames
```

which is a list.
Then, the line `union(rownames(ismr0[[1]]), name)` adds the elements of `name` to the list, which doesn't contain those **single** elements and you get something like :

```
[[1]]
[1] "l1" "l2" "l3" "l4" "l5"

[[2]]
[1] "l6"  "l7"  "l8"  "l9"  "l10"

[[3]]
[1] "l11" "l12" "l13" "l14" "l15"

[[4]]
[1] "l1"

[[5]]
[1] "l2"
```

You need to use `sapply`, which returns a vector instead of a list.